# Identifying the Registration Details using OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, pandas, computer-vision, opencv

I need help on how to check if  dataFrame contain a recognized text.

I just have to use this

```
df.loc[df['Col'].str.contains(txt, case=False)]
```

but i was not successful.

Code :

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import pandas as pd
 
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe"
 
img = cv2.imread('image/tt.jpg')
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry.shape[:2]
gry = gry[int(h/4) + 40:int(h/2)-20, int(w/2):int((w*3)/4)]
blr = cv2.GaussianBlur(gry, (3, 3), 0)
thr = cv2.threshold(gry, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr)
print(txt)

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,"CMA CGM"],[2,"7040"],[3,"ED7485"]],columns=('ID','Col'))
Res = df.loc[df['Col'].str.contains(txt, case=False)]
print(Res)

cv2.imshow("thr", thr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The image used in code :
[https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/CMA_CGM_container.JPG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4SJm.jpg)

My Output :

```
CMA CGM

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ID, Col]
Index: []
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What does `print(Res)` output?

Comment: @U12-Forward To print the selected row whose column value equals to the recognized text

Comment: Show me the output of `print(Res)`

Comment: @U12-Forward the Output of : `print(df.loc[df['Col'].str.contains('CMA CGM', case=False)])` is `ID      Col
0   1  CMA CGM`

Comment: What's the type of `Res`?